# Merging features with the same values within feature class

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, geoprocessing, dissolve, feature-class

I have a feature class of land parcels that contain `"ownername"` and `"land_use_code"` fields. Some of these features have the same values despite being two different parcels in different locations. For example, two parcels have ownername `'Jon Doe'` and land_use_code `'1001'` but are on opposite sides of a town.

I want to merge those two parcels into a single feature based on those values and any others like that while also keeping all the other fields that are not relevant to the merge. Is there a way to do this for thousands of features at once in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) does exactly that:

> Aggregates features based on specified attributes.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the other fields that are not dissolved. The feature class has 5 other fields that I want to keep in the new one.

Comment: It might work to Spatial join them back. It depends on your data

Comment: This worked. Thanks!